# file with permission lrwxrwxrwx does not show any link on "ls -l" command

Tags: files, permissions, symlink

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 tomcat tomcat    27 Oct 17 00:23 work
```

This is my file(link) I want to go inside a directory within it to `rm` a file and then copy the new one. But it says `permission denied` and does not show any link. How can I do what I want.

Comment: What are the permissions of the directory you're linking the file?

Comment: 1. how did you created the link? 2. what are the permissions of destination directory (the one you are pointing with your link) 3. what user are you using while performing your commands?

Comment: do you want to remove a link that points to a directory ? try `rm work` without the trailing `/`

Comment: thanks for comments. I used setenforce 1 and then i'm able to get into the folder

Answer (score -1):

Use `setenforce 1` for such condition when unable to browse through the folder